# Woocommerce Custom Shop Page (archive-product.php) and Search Results Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created [a custom shop page](http://sizeslim.com/shop/) by copying the `archive-product.php` page into `mytheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. Everything is working fine with that.

However, if I search anything, underneath the 'custom content' on the page it displays:

> No products were found matching your selection.

It's not properly displaying the search results due to the fact that (I think) they both use that same template.

I have read that the search results page uses the same template as the woocommerce shop.

So two questions:

1. I think that I need to change the php for the search so that it searches everything and not just the products.
2. Is there a way to redirect/change where the search results are displayed rather than just showing in the shop?

Comment: is this a smart way to spam?

Comment: This is definitely not spam. If you enter anything into the search bar in the header, you can see my issue here.

Comment: We shouldn't need to check on an external link to see what is breaking. Give some more description and eventually a screenshot.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't used this before, but haven't been able to find an answer anywhere, so forgive my lack of protocol.

Comment: Like I said, I have edited the archive-product.php template and copied it into my child theme folder to display the custom shop page. I have read that the search results page uses the same template as the woocommerce shop. As of now, if I search anything it displays "No products were found matching your selection." underneath the custom content on the page.

So two questions:

1. I think that I need to change the php for the search so that it searches everything not just the products.

2. Is there a way to redirect/change where the search results are displayed rather than just showing the shop

Comment: please, don't ask question in the comments but edit your question instead. I already edited with your first version of the comment. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the help so far @fantaghirocco ! Sorry such a newb at this board.

Comment: You're welcome but editing question gives "points" so *in the logic of this site* there's no need to thank for a so little aid. Although I have subscribed three years ago, I started actively from July so here I'm a sort of newbie too. When you have the time, consider to read  [ask] and [mcve] between the [help] section. If I'm allowed, there's one rule above all: *quality questions will probably have quality answers*. If your question is clear, probably someone who knows about it will answer soon. Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: In particular, I think your question lacks a clear description of what you intend to see that you aren't, and the code that is (not) generating that content. Screenshots can be helpful, as well as mock ups, and of course code snippets.